# How to delete a particular sentence from a paragraph based on string match in that sentence?

Tags: php, string

For example I have the following paragraph

> When you are ready to complete the interview, click Interview me . Don't worry, you will have a chance to practice before you take the full interview. The job closing date is December 30, 2030 so make sure you have your response back to us by then. Thanks for applying.

I need to delete the entire sentence containing 'December 30, 2030'.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways, but I would just use this method:

1. Explode your string on `.`
2. Go through your values and keep only the ones, where `December 30, 2030` is not present.

But this will have problems if you havea `.` inside a sentence. In this case, you will need to think of a different way to sepperate your sentences from each other.

```
$string = "When you are ready to complete the interview, click Interview me . Don't worry, you will have a chance to practice before you take the full interview. The job closing date is December 30, 2030 so make sure you have your response back to us by then. Thanks for applying.";
$search = "December 30, 2030";

$sentences = explode( '.', $string );

$new_string = '';
foreach ( $sentences as $sentece )
{
    if ( !strpos( $sentece, $search ) )
        $new_string .= $sentece . '.';
}
```

Output:

```
When you are ready to complete the interview, click Interview me . Don't worry, you will have a chance to practice before you take the full interview. Thanks for applying.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just break it into sentences first?  Then run your tests against each sentence and only include it in the output if your tests tell you that you should include it?

Answer (score -1):

An easy solution would be a replacement

```
str_replace('December 30, 2030', '', 'When you are ready to complete the interview, click Interview me . Don't worry, you will have a chance to practice before you take the full interview. The job closing date is December 30, 2030 so make sure you have your response back to us by then. Thanks for applying');
```

This way you can also change it with the current date :

```
str_replace('December 30, 2030', date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'), 'When you are ready to complete the interview, click Interview me . Don't worry, you will have a chance to practice before you take the full interview. The job closing date is December 30, 2030 so make sure you have your response back to us by then. Thanks for applying');
```

Comment: hi,i need to replacing the sentence..not the string.

Comment: This will replace only the short string, not remove the whole sentence. PS: You have syntax errors in both of your examples.